# Angular 6: ERROR TypeError: "... is not a function" - but it is

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently really confused, because I get the `ERROR TypeError: "_this.device.addKeysToObj is not a function"`. But I implemented the function, so I have no idea what's the problem or why it is not callable. I have tried the code with Firefox and chrome, both through the same error.

The error is in line `this.device.addKeysToObj(this.result.results[0]);`

Here is my class:

```
export class Device {
    id: number;
    deviceID: string;
    name: string;
    location: string;
    deviceType: string;
    subType: string;
    valueNamingMap: Object;

    addKeysToObj(deviceValues: object): void {
        for (let key of Object.keys(deviceValues).map((key) => { return key })) {
            if (!this.valueNamingMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.valueNamingMap[key] = '';
            }
        }
        console.log(this, deviceValues);
    }
}
```

And that is the call:

```
export class BatterieSensorComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() device: Device;
    public result: Page<Value> = new Page<Value>();

    //[..]

    ngOnInit() {
      this.valueService.list('', this.device).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(this.device);  // NEW edit 1
          this.result = res;
          if (this.result.count > 0) 
          {
            this.device.addKeysToObj(this.result.results[0]);
          }
        }
      )
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 1**

Logging `this.device` see comment in code above:

```
{
    deviceID: "000000001" 
    deviceType: "sensor"    ​
    id: 5    ​
    location: "-"
​    name: "Batteries"    ​
    subType: "sensor"    ​
    valueNamingMap:
      Object { v0: "vehicle battery", v1: "Living area battery" }
    <prototype>: Object { … } 
}
```

**Edit 2**

Part of the device.service code:

```
list(url?: string, deviceType?: string, subType?: string): Observable<Page<Device>> {
  if(!url) url = `${this.url}/devices/`;
  if(deviceType) url+= '?deviceType=' + deviceType;
  if(subType) url+= '&subType=' + subType;

  return this.httpClient.get<Page<Device>>(url, { headers: this.headers })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('LIST devices', new Page<Device>()))
    );
}
```

The call in the parent component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.deviceService.list('', 'sensor', ).subscribe(
    res => { 
      this.devices = res.results;
    }
  )
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet" *ngFor="let device of devices">
    <app-batterie-sensor [device]="device"></app-batterie-sensor>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

## Original answer

This is a common gotcha with Typescript, you say `device` is of type `Device`, but it isn't. It has all of the same properties as a `Device` would, but since it isn't a `Device` it does not have the expected methods.

You need to ensure that you instantiate `Device` for each entry in your `Page`, perhaps in the `ngOnInit` of the parent component:

I don't know the structure of `Page`, but if it's an array try the following.

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.deviceService.list('', 'sensor', ).subscribe(
    res => { 
      this.devices = res.results.map(x => Object.assign(new Device(), x));
    }
  )
}
```

---

## Further explanation

Let's try a typescript example, as this behaviour doesn't have anything to do with Angular. We'll use `localStorage` to represent data coming from an external source, but this works just the same with HTTP.

```
interface SimpleValue {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

function loadFromStorage<T>(): T {
    // Get from local storage.
    // Ignore the potential null value because we know this key will exist.
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('MyKey') as string;

    // Note how there is no validation in this function.
    // I can't validate that the loaded value is actually T
    // because I don't know what T is.
    return JSON.parse(storedValue);
}

const valueToSave: SimpleValue = { a: 1, b: 'b' };
localStorage.setItem('MyKey', JSON.stringify(valueToSave));

const loadedValue = loadFromStorage<SimpleValue>();

// It works!
console.log(loadedValue);
```

That works just fine, awesome. A typescript interface is purely a compile-time structure and, unlike a class, it has no equivalent in JavaScript - it's just a developer hint. But this also means that if you create an interface for an external value, like `SimpleValue` above, and get it *wrong* then the compiler is still going to trust you know what you're talking about, it can't possibly validate this at compile time.

What about loading a class from an external source? How does it differ? If we take the example above and change `SimpleValue` into a class without changing anything else then it will still work. But there is a difference. Unlike interfaces, classes are transpiled into their JavaScript equivalent, in other words, they exist past the point of compilation. In our above example this doesn't cause a problem, so let's try an example that does cause a problem.

```
class SimpleClass {
    constructor(public a: number, public b: string) { }

    printA() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
}

const valueToSave: SimpleClass = new SimpleClass(1, 'b');
localStorage.setItem('MyKey', JSON.stringify(valueToSave));

const loadedValue = loadFromStorage<SimpleClass>();

console.log(loadedValue.a); // 1
console.log(loadedValue.b); // 'b'
loadedValue.printA(); // TypeError: loadedValue.printA is not a function
```

The loaded value had the properties we expected, but not the methods, uh oh! The problem is that methods get created when `new SimpleClass` is called. When we created `valueToSave` we did indeed instantiate the class, but then we turned it into a JSON string and sent it off elsewhere, and JSON has no concept of methods so the information was lost. When we loaded the data in `loadFromStorage` we did *not* call `new SimpleClass`, we just trusted that the caller knew what the stored type would be.

How do we deal with this? Let's go back to Angular for a moment and consider a common use case: dates. JSON has no Date type, JavaScript does, so how do we retrieve a date from our server and have it work as a date? Here's a pattern I like to use.

```
interface UserContract {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    lastLogin: string; // ISO string representation of a Date.
}

class UserModel {
    id: string; // Same as above
    name: string; // Same as above
    lastLogin: Date; // Different!

    constructor(contract: UserContract) {
        // This is the explicit version of the constructor.
        this.id = contract.id;
        this.name = contract.name;
        this.lastLogin = new Date(contract.lastLogin);

        // If you want to avoid the boilerplate (and safety) of the explicit constructor
        // an alternative is to use Object.assign:
        // Object.assign(this, contract, { lastLogin: new Date(contract.lastLogin) });
    }

    printFriendlyLastLogin() {
        console.log(this.lastLogin.toLocaleString());
    }
}

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
class MyService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    getUser(): Observable<UserModel> {
        // Contract represents the data being returned from the external data source.
        return this.httpClient.get<UserContract>('my.totally.not.real.api.com')
            .pipe(
              map(contract => new UserModel(contract))
            );
    }
}

@Component({
    // bla bla
})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getUser().subscribe(x => {
            x.printFriendlyLastLogin(); // this works
            console.log(x.lastLogin.getFullYear()); // this works too
        });
    }
}
```

Perhaps a bit verbose, but it's the most robust and flexible pattern I've used for dealing with rich frontend models coming from flat backend contracts.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can you share a bit more on why does this happen? Why the objects are not the same?

Comment: It's not a Device unless you explicitly instantiate it with `new Device()`, which was not being done in the original question.

Comment: I was looking for some more details regarding this behaviour. The post [Angular HTTP tips for success](https://davidpine.net/blog/angular-http-gotchas/) helped me a lot.

Comment: Ha, came looking for the solution to the function thing, and immediately found a nice way to clone objects.

Comment: This explains a lot of things! Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You might have landed here with a different problem than in the accepted answer: If you're using Angular's services and forget the `@Injectable`, with Angular Ivy you get a runtime exception like this:

```
ERROR TypeError: ConfigurationServiceImpl.\u0275fac is not a function
```

The correct solution is to ad `@Injectable` also to implementations, e.g:

```js
// do not omit the @Injectable(), or you'll end up with the error message!
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationServiceImpl implements ConfigurationService {
...
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
  useClass: ConfigurationServiceImpl,
})
export abstract class ConfigurationService {
...
}
```

also see [Angular 7 TypeError: service.x is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071850/angular-7-typeerror-service-x-is-not-a-function).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tested two solutions that work for me

Wrap the code in a ***setTimeout***

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeOut({ // START OF SETTIMEOUT
    this.deviceService.list('', 'sensor', ).subscribe(
      res => { 
        this.devices = res.results.map(x => Object.assign(new Device(), x));
      }
    )
  }); // END OF SETTIMEOUT
}
```

**OR**

The **other** solution was to add a ***condition***

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(typeof this.deviceService.list === 'function'){ // START OF CONDITION
    this.deviceService.list('', 'sensor', ).subscribe(
      res => { 
        this.devices = res.results.map(x => Object.assign(new Device(), x));
      }
    )
  } // END OF CONDITION
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @UncleDave already explained, you're only mapping the values with corresponding names to the Typescript object but you're not creating the expected class object with it.  It's pretty confusing, I know.

`Object.assign()` will solve your current problem, but not if you have nested objects.  Then you will have to do `Object.assign()` for each nested object as well, which can get tedious if you have to do this in multiple places in your codebase.

I suggest an alternative: [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer)  With this you can mark your nested fields with annotations that tell the compiler how to create the nested objects as well. With this you only need to use the `plainToClass()` method to map your top level object and all the underlying fields will also have the correct types/objects.

### Example

Let's say we have two classes:

```
class Parent {
    name: string;
    child: Child;

    public getText(): string {
        return 'parent text';
    }
}

class Child{
    name: string;

    public getText(): string {
        return 'child text';
    }
}
```

**The first case** we already know doesn't work:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = parentJson; // note: compiler accepts this because parentJson is any.  
        // If we tried to assign the json structure directly to 'parent' it would fail because the compiler knows that the method getText() is missing!

console.log(parent.getText()); // throws the error that parent.getText() is not a function as expected
```

**Second case** using `Object.assign()`:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = Object.assign(parentJson); 

console.log(parent.getText()); // this works
console.log(parent.child.getText()); // throws error that parent.child.getText() is not a function!
```

to make it work, we would have to do the following:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = Object.assign(parentJson);
parent.child = Object.assign(parentJson.child);

console.log(parent.getText()); // this works
console.log(parent.child.getText()); // this works
```

**Third case** with class-transformer:

First modify the parent class so that the child mapping is defined:

```
class Parent {
    name: string;
    @Type(() => Child)
    child: Child;

    public getText(): string {
        return 'parent text';
    }
}
```

then you can map to the parent object:

```
let parentJson: any = {name: 'parent name', child: {name: 'child name'}};
let parent: Parent = plainToClass(Parent, parentJson);

console.log(parent.getText()); // this works
console.log(parent.child.getText()); // this works
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer I gave in this post helped me out. I got it from a YT video basically said you needed to check if that class's method exists.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76186682/21161371

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).