# How to fix Type Error not a function in angular

Tags: angular

Have a simple website choose your own adventure component. Get this error whenever I try to call the functions for the classes I made to represent story events.

```
export class ZombieCharacterOutcome {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    public characteristic: ZombiePlayerCharacteristic;
    events: string[];

    public getNextEvent(): string {
        var rand = Math.random() * this.events.length;
        return this.events[rand];
    }
}
```

I am using a firestore database to store data, this is also how new outcomes are initialized.

```
getCharaterOutcome(outcomeID: string): Observable<ZombieCharacterOutcome> 
{
    console.log(outcomeID);
    return this.db.doc('characterOutcomes/' + 
    outcomeID).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(choice => {
    const data = choice.payload.data() as ZombieCharacterOutcome;
    if (data) {
       data.id = choice.payload.id;
    }
    return data;
  }));
}
```

And this is code from Angular Component being called on the front end...

```
nextEvent() {
    if(this.eventCount < this.maxEvent) {
        this.characterService.getCharacterEvent(this.currentOutcome.getNextEvent()).subscribe(event => {
            this.currentOutcome = null;
            this.currentEvent = event;
            this.loadChoices();
        });
    } else {
        this.currentEvent = null;
        this.currentChoices = [];
        this.currentOutcome = null;
    }
}
```

> ERROR TypeError: this.currentOutcome.getNextEvent is not a function
>       at ZombieCharacterComponentComponent.push../src/app/zombie-character-component/zombie-character-component.component.ts.ZombieCharacterComponentComponent.nextEvent (zombie-character-component.component.ts:60)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ZombieCharacterComponentComponent.html:28)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
>       at core.js:8154
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (platform-browser.js:988)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)

Comment: Hi, please provide the code, where you instantiate the `ZombieCharacterOutcome` class.

Comment: Refer to this answer, it might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764292/10262090

Comment: if you change getNextEvent(): string to getNextEvent() do you still get the error?

Comment: @DylanAnlezark removing the type did not affect the error

Comment: @Batajus I have included the code used to retrieve from my firestore DB. This function is called to instantiate new ZombieCharacterOutcomes

Comment: Thanks all. I am new to typescript this threw me for a loop

Answer (score 0):

The ZombieCharacterOutcome variable had not yet been instantiated.

I reworked my getCharacterOutcomeCode to create a new ZombieCharacterOutcome before returning and all works now.