# Angular 7 TypeError: service.x is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a routing service and want to inject it into my nav component. But when i call a method on it it throws `TypeError: routingService.getRequestedPage is not a function`. Yesterday I had a very similar problem with another service, unfortunately I forgot how I solved this. I generated the service it with the terminal.

`src/app/nav/nav.component.ts` constructor:

```js
constructor(private templateService: TemplateService, private routingService: RoutingService) {
    this.getTemplates();
    if (this.routingService.getRequestedPage() === 'home') {
      this.showHome();
    }
  }
```

`src/app/nav/nav.component.ts` import:

```js
import {RoutingService} from '../shared/routing.service';
```

`src/app/shared/routing.service.ts`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingService {

  private requestedPage: string;

  constructor() {
    this.requestedPage = 'home';
  }

  requestPage(page: string) {
    this.requestedPage = page;
  }

  getRequestedPage() {
    return this.requestedPage;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your import for `RoutingService` look like?

Comment: have you tried replacing method defination to "getRequestedPage(): string"

Comment: @Viqas edited post and added import statement

Comment: @MihirDave this worked! could you explain why?

Comment: Not that this is directly applicable to the situation described above, but you can get this error due to a circular dependency between services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of putting the providedIn part just put @Injectable() then in your app.module.ts file add the service under providers. Then when you write

```js
constructor(private whateverService: WhateverService) {
}
```

In any component you should have access without errors. I see you have it as private in the snippet but thats one that always trips me up so make sure its private when injecting into the constructor.

Comment: This worked, could you maybe explain why this does work and the other doesn’t?

Comment: Im not exactly sure because Ive always used the method I described but if I had to guess I would say that the "providedIn: 'root'" would allow you to add it to ANY modules providers array and it would achieve the same as putting it in the app.module.ts providers. Not sure though so you would have to try to confirm.

Comment: Most likely you also have other modules apart from the App.module. And you are trying to use that service in one of those other modules. So providedIn: 'root' will try to make that service available in main module instead of the actual component module where you have imported the service.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can also be caused by creating a circular dependency. If service A is injected into service B, and service B is injected into service A, calling A.foo() from service B will cause the error "A.foo() is not a function". In fact, A will not be correctly instantiated and have no methods or properties.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, i was getting this error also... In my app.module.ts file i had a useFactory constructor  order issue:

I get this error:
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: appConfig.get is not a function TypeError: appConfig.get is not a function

**Fail:**

```
useFactory:
                (
                    permissionService: NgxPermissionsService
                    appConfig: AppConfigService, //the order matters
                ) =>
                async () => {
const promise = await appConfig
                            .get()
                            .toPromise()
                            .then((x) => {
                                //console.log('app.module.ts: toPromise.then() Env:', x);
                                appConfig.setConfig(x);
                                return x;
                            }); //await toPromise causes the env to be updated before running the rest of the code
                        return promise;
```

**Success:**

```
useFactory:
                (
                    appConfig: AppConfigService, //the order matters
                    permissionService: NgxPermissionsService
                ) =>
                async () => {
const promise = await appConfig
                            .get()
                            .toPromise()
                            .then((x) => {
                                //console.log('app.module.ts: toPromise.then() Env:', x);
                                appConfig.setConfig(x);
                                return x;
                            }); //await toPromise causes the env to be updated before running the rest of the code
                        return promise;
```