# Angular LocalStorage Service setter and getters not recognized as functions

Tags: angular, local-storage

I created a setter and getter functions for localStorage service in angular and inject it in my home component, but I am getting an error **is not a function** in navigator console and I also can't see anything in dev tools application windows local storage section.

LocalStorage Service is injected into App Module correctly.

> Local Storage Service

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LOCAL_STORAGE, StorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage-service';

//Types

const GROUPE = "GROUPE";
const ALONE = "ALONE";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalStorageService {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService) { }

  setGroupeType(val: boolean) {
    this.storage.set(GROUPE, JSON.stringify(val));
  }
  getGroupeType(): boolean {
    return JSON.parse(this.storage.get(GROUPE));
  }

  setAloneType(val: boolean) {
    this.storage.set(ALONE, JSON.stringify(val));
  }

  getAloneType(): boolean {
    return JSON.parse(this.storage.get(ALONE));
  }
}
```

> HomeComponent.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'src/app/services/local-storage.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public setGroupeType() {
    this.localStorageService.setAloneType(false);
    this.localStorageService.setGroupeType(true);
    console.log(this.localStorageService.getGroupeType());
  }

  public setAloneType() {
    this.localStorageService.setGroupeType(false);
    this.localStorageService.setAloneType(true);
    console.log(this.localStorageService.getAloneType());
  }
}
```

> HomeComponent.html

```html
<ng-template #groupSelected>
  <div class="floating">
    <div>
      <input type="text" required />
      <label>Skriv inn gruppekode</label>
      <a [routerLink]="['../type']" (click)="setGroupeType()"><img src="assets/images/arrow-light.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
</div>
<div class="col alene">
  <span>Alene</span>
  <a [routerLink]="['../type']" (click)="setAloneType()">
    <img src="assets/images/arrow-light.svg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: I am having this.localStorageService.getGroupeType() is not a function error

Comment: Maybe try recreating it on stackblitz, because it looks fine.

Comment: remove providedIn: 'root' and register your service on the module. The error should go away.

Comment: Well today it is working, I think cash clear extension and restarting the project was the solution, as the service probably needed a restart to work! Not sure. @Steve I did keep it and it is working fine ? care to explain why should I / shouldn't I keep it.

Comment: yeah, I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071850/angular-7-typeerror-service-x-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Basically just clear cache, close the instance of ng serve and restart again.

Ps: Clearing cache just to be safe.