# Reactive forms regex.test is not a function

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a model that uses reactive forms and keeps giving me the error of regex.test is not a function.

The model is the following:

```
import { date, email, maxDate, maxLength, minDate, minLength, pattern, prop, required } from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators";

export class UserInfo {

  @required()
  public firstName: string;

  @required()
  public lastName: string;

  @pattern({expression: {pattern: /(^\+?[\d\W-/]{4,16}$)/ } })
  @minLength({value: 4})
  public phoneNumber: string;

}
```

And the error

```
ERROR TypeError: regex.test is not a function
    at Function.isValid (reactive-form-validators.js:719)
    at reactive-form-validators.js:3418
    at forms.js:1155
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:1151)
    at RxFormControl.validator (forms.js:1096)
    at RxFormControl._runValidator (forms.js:3438)
    at RxFormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3399)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:3843)
    at new RxFormControl (reactive-form-validators.js:2017)
```

happens when on the component I'm doing on the `ngOnInit()`:

```
this.baseForm = this.formBuilder.formGroup(this.user) as RxFormGroup;
```

What is even stranger is that it only happens when I actually have data on the phoneNumber. If my phoneNumber is empty it works perfectly.

I even tested the following:

```
this.user.phoneNumber = "";
this.baseForm = this.formBuilder.formGroup(this.user) as RxFormGroup;
```

And this works. What is even stranger to me is that I did a small example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxweb-phonenumber-pattern-validator) and there it also works without any problem even with data.

Comment: FYI: always place the literal `-` in a character class at the start or end: `[\d\W\/-]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've also tried that, but I ended up with the same problem

Comment: Yes, because the main issue is in the code.

Comment: Probably your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763745/angular-6-error-typeerror-is-not-a-function-but-it-is)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've created a new instance, mapped by hand, nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find out a solution and it was the following:

```
this.baseForm = this.formBuilder.formGroup(this.user) as RxFormGroup;
    (this.baseForm .controls.phoneNumber as FormControl)
      .addValidators(
        [TextValidator.regexMatchValidator(new RegExp(/(^\+?[\d\W-/]{4,16}$)/), "error message")]);
```

basically add a validator after the form initialization

Answer (score 1):

It is working in my machine, please check the below image :

[image]

If you have sample not working example of pattern then please share the same

Comment: it also works on the example I've made on stackblitz, I don't know why it does not on my solution

Comment: @heisenberg No Problem, It's working in my local machine. The provided screenshot is not stackblitz runing example. Interesting issue, I would like to deep dive into it if you provide some more details on this

Comment: @heisenberg Would be great if we can use stackoverflow chat room or rxweb gitter chat channel

Comment: I don't know how to open a chat room :D if you want we can do it, just start it eheh

Comment: @heisenberg I don’t know how to create a chat room, Can you please come on gitter : https://gitter.im/rxweb-project/rxweb