# Error in comparing two object in Angular/Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have the following variables in my `Jasmine` test

```
  tag1:Tag;
  tag2:Tag;
  tag3:Tag;
  supportedTagsArray:Array<Tag>;
  supportedTags: SupportedTags;
```

They are objects of the following classes

```
export class Tag{
  constructor(
    public course:string,
    public subject:string,
    public topic:string
  ){}
}

export class SupportedTags{
  'supported-tags':Array<Tag>;
  constructor(
    supportedTags:Array<Tag>
  ){
    this['supported-tags'] = supportedTags;
  }
}
```

I am initializing them in the following way in my `spec`

```
    this.tag1 = new Tag('c1','s1','t1');
    this.tag2 = new Tag('c2','s2','t2');
    this.tag3 = new Tag('c3','s3','t3');
    this.supportedTagsArray = new Array<Tag>(this.tag1,this.tag2,this.tag3);
    this.supportedTags = new SupportedTags(this.supportedTagsArray);
```

In the `spec`, I am comparing the values in the following way

```
expect(updateQuestionComponent.supportedTags["supported-tags"])
 .toEqual(questionManagementService.supportedTags);
```

`updateQuestionComponent.supportedTags` is defined in my `Angular` `.ts` class as follows

```
supportedTags:SupportedTags;
```

and its value  is populated on receiving data from an `Observable`.

```
let resultObject = JSON.parse(result.additionalInfo) as SupportedTags;
          console.log('got tag object ',resultObject);
          let tags:Tag[] = [];
          console.log(resultObject["supported-tags"].length);
          for(let count=0;count<resultObject["supported-tags"].length;count++)
          {
            console.log("count is ",count);
            console.log("adding tag: ",resultObject["supported-tags"][count] as Tag);
            tags.push(resultObject["supported-tags"][count] as Tag);
          }
          let supportedTags = new SupportedTags(tags);


          this.supportedTags = supportedTags;
```

The data received from the observable is

```
    Result {result: "success", additionalInfo: "{"supported-tags":[{"course":"c1","subject":"s1","…2"},{"course":"c3","subject":"s3","topic":"t3"}]}"}
additionalInfo: "{"supported-tags":[{"course":"c1","subject":"s1","topic":"t1"},{"course":"c2","subject":"s2","topic":"t2"},{"course":"c3","subject":"s3","topic":"t3"}]}"
result: "success"
```

My test case fails with the following error `Expected [ Object({ course: 'c1', subject: 's1', topic: 't1' }), Object({ course: 'c2', subject: 's2', topic: 't2' }), Object({ course: 'c3', subject: 's3', topic: 't3' }) ] to equal SupportedTags({ supported-tags: [ Tag({ course: 'c1', subject: 's1', topic: 't1' }), Tag({ course: 'c2', subject: 's2', topic: 't2' }), Tag({ course: 'c3', subject: 's3', topic: 't3' }) ] }).`

Why?

UPDATE
There was one error in the comparison.

```
expect(updateQuestionComponent.supportedTags["supported-tags"]).toEqual(questionManagementService.supportedTags);
```

should be

```
expect(updateQuestionComponent.supportedTags["supported-expect(updateQuestionComponent.supportedTags["supported-tags"]).toEqual(questionManagementService.supportedTags["supported-tags"]);
```

But after fixing it, I am getting the following error

```
Expected $[0] to be a kind of Tag, but was Object({ course: 'c1', subject: 's1', topic: 't1' }).
Expected $[1] to be a kind of Tag, but was Object({ course: 'c2', subject: 's2', topic: 't2' }).
Expected $[2] to be a kind of Tag, but was Object({ course: 'c3', subject: 's3', topic: 't3' }).
```

I suppose I a mixing thing between general `Object` and object of a class but I can't figure out where I am making the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the casting to `Tag` using `as` wasn't working as I expected. If I explicitly create instance of `Tag` then the comparison works

```
console.log("count is ",count);
            let castedTag = (resultObject["supported-tags"][count]) as Tag;
            console.log("adding tag: ",castedTag);
            let tempTag = new Tag(castedTag.course,castedTag.subject,castedTag.topic);
            tags.push(tempTag);
```

But I don't understnad why? Happy to accept another answer with explanation

I added some debug prints to check the type of `castedTag` and `tempTag`. My conclusion is that using `as` doesn't change the underlying type of the object. `as` just allows an object to be treated as of some other type. So `castedTag` is still an `Object` even if I am using `as`. If I want `Tag`, I need to do a `new Tag`.

Comment: Your conclusion is 100% correct, I've written an explanation on a mostly unrelated question, but you may find it relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763745/angular-6-error-typeerror-is-not-a-function-but-it-is/51764292#51764292