# Class not being loaded, don't know where 'cached' class is coming from

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm developing an Angular 10 app using visual studio code. I've got some basic classes located in /app/_model/.ts

for some reason I don't understand when I debug the application in MS Edge and I look at the 'loaded scripts' I see that classes 'a' and 'c' are loaded (from the model folder), but some reason 'b' isn't loaded. If I try to set a breakpoint in class 'b' I also get an 'unbound breakpoint'.
When editing the code VS Code all my changes to class 'b' do seem to come through. So if I add a method, say 'test', to class 'b' I can call it from any of the components. However during runtime I get the following exception in edge: TypeError: _a.test is not a function. Also the app does seem to work, but it uses some old version of class 'b'. No idea where that one is coming from.

I'm really puzzled as to why this only happens for this one particular class and also why now. This is not a new class for this project, it was working perfectly fine just a week ago.

Any clues?

Comment: This won't actually clarfiy why this happens, but I have made the experience that debugging a WebApp is done easiest with a lot of `console.log()`. It's fast and you don't have to get nuts about such debugger problems. Give it a try.

Comment: The problem is that the class really isn't being updated. I can add the console.log() to class 'a', 'c' or wherever and they'll show up, but this class 'b' just isn't being updated. So any console.log I add there won't show. It's not about debugging, it's about the class not loading at all.

Comment: Does the issue also occur in other browsers? Have you tried to clear browser cache and test again? Besides, you can try to check ["Disable cache"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqUhB.png) in F12 Network tab if you're using Edge Chromium.

Comment: Yes, the exact same things happen whether I'm using Firefox or Edge Chromium. "Disable Cache" also doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I already found out what's happening. The objects are coming in via .NET5 WebApi and are being send using json. The classes 'a' and 'c' which I thought were working correctly actually send serialized some properties which shouldn't have been serialized.
The property, or function for that matter, only class 'b' was not serialized (which was good), but hence the class never got instantiated. I first needed to initialize the class with the json object, much like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763745/angular-6-error-typeerror-is-not-a-function-but-it-is)